# How to Populate Records in tabs dynamically in filemaker pro advance

Tags: filemaker

I am using FileMaker Pro Advance . I want to design product catalog which include Product types in tabs bar or buttons, and when user select any type of product , It will populate the sub category of product.

Currently I am fetching type of product from product_type table. When I am using radio button or Drop Down, it fills but I want to show it in tabs or buttons that populate at the time of load of layout. Is it Possible ???

```
Have anyone Solution for the same. Thanks in Advance....

Anirudh Pandey
ani.pandey.007@gmail.com
```

Comment: This should work fine, what have you tried/did you have problems implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but have you tried a FileMaker tab set?